# Bind checkbox angular with input

Tags: angular, checkbox, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

Using tour of heroes for a a reference that I am trying to modify for what I want to do.

When the page loads I will have multiple choices for a user to decide which item is to be used.

I want the checkbox unselected unless the list item is selected.
Two problems are the checkbox doesnt show unless i select an item, and selecting an item doesnt check the box. just makes it appear.
[Image of two boxes selecting input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnl2R.png)
sample code below.
HTML CODE

```
<div class="card-box">
                        <div class="card-row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h3>Duns Number <span class="float-right" *ngIf="selectedHero">
                                        <input #selectedHero id="selectedHero" type="checkbox" [checked]="selectedHeroBox"
                                            (change)="onselectedHero(selectedHero.checked)" type="checkbox">
                                    </span>
                                </h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <p class="greyColor">numeric field</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row padTop30">
                            <div class="col-md-12 selItem" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                <ul class="heroes">
                                    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
                                        (click)="onSelect(hero)">{{hero.name}}
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Component

```
heroes = HEROES;
selectedHero: Hero;
selectedHeroBox: boolean;

onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
}
public onselectedHero(value: boolean) {
    this.selectedHeroBox = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the question but is this what you are looking for? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ojqlrf

Comment: Glad you could pull my question out of that. I was able to modify what I have to hit the api pulling results back for each card.

I greatly appreciate it